# How to find a css class or id using inspect element

Tags: html, css

I can't seem to find the css class or id that are assigned to an empty space in my home page, in other pages I don't have this problem.

What I'm trying to do is to add a padding-top to all the pages so that way my fixed header will not overlap the page container ( main content )

The media queries is not working and even the percentage and vh vw don't resolve this issue

Here's some screenshots :

[View 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VlC83.png)

[View 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NZRbq.png)

```
header.site-header {
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 99999;
    background-color: #fff;
    width: 100%;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 1px 2px 0px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.36);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 1px 2px 0px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.36);
    box-shadow: 0px 1px 2px 0px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.36);
}
```

Main Content :

```
#PageContainer {
    height: 100%;
    background: #b43434;
}
```

HTML

```
<div id="PageContainer">
  <header class="site-header">
  <div class="wrapper">
        {% include 'header' %}
        {% include 'menu' %}

      </div>
    </header> <!-- end header -->
    <div class="breadcrumb-wrapper">
        {% include 'breadcrumb' %}
    </div>
    <main class="{% if template != 'index' %}wrapper {% endif %}main-content" >
      {% if template != 'index' %}

      {% endif %}
      {{ content_for_layout }}

    </main>

    <!-- begin site-footer -->
    <footer class="site-footer" >
      <div class="wrapper">
        {% include 'footer' %}
      </div>
    </footer>
    <footer class="site-footer2" >
      <div class="wrapper">
        {% include 'footer2' %}
      </div>
    </footer>
    <!-- //site-footer -->
```

Thanks!

Comment: An example of what I'm trying to achieve :
http://jsfiddle.net/avrahamcool/Mspxt/4/

Comment: Why aren't you adding a `padding-top` to `#PageContainer` equal to the header's height?

Comment: @andrei-gheorghiu Because I have 2 different headers ( desktop + mobile/hamburger ) If i set a fixed value for the header both change the appareance, I don't know how to change only the mobile header height.

Comment: Use a `@media` query and set different paddings at different widths. Besides, fixed menu on mobile? Really bad experience. Just a hamburger, finger size (min `35px * 35px`). Animate it to full screen, scrollable when opened.

Comment: @andrei-gheorghiu What's wrong with this code? #PageContainer {
    height: 100%;
    background: #f00;
}

@ media only screen and (min-width : 960px) {
    #PageContainer {
        padding-top: 25px;
    }
}
 
@ media only screen and (min-width : 1200px) {
    #PageContainer {
        padding-top: 125px;
    }
}

Comment: It has spaces between `@` and `media` in `@media`, @Mars.

Comment: @andrei-gheorghiu I know I know It's just because stackoverflow tells me that only one user can be notified using the (@)user function! Thanks! Problem solved :)